# Does Camelot ADO.NET Connect support Hadoop access?

Tags: hadoop, ado.net, camelot-.net-connector

Just wanted to know if Camelot Connect would be abble to have Hadoop access support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be possible yes, Camelot .NET Connector is basically an SQL interpreter for API's. There are no Hadoop support at the moment though.

If SQL for Hadoop is your goal there are several tools available for this or are you looking for a single SQL API for SharePoint, Hadoop and more Camelot Connector technology would be a good option. Contact bendsoft for more information.